# What does it mean for a review to be "synthetic"?

Tags: terminology, literature-review, review-articles

The term "synthetic" is often used to describe review papers, such as in the title

*Multi-touch tables and the relationship with collaborative classroom pedagogies: A synthetic review*

What does it mean for a paper to be "synthetic"?

Comment: see https://www.researchtoaction.org/2020/05/synthetic-literature-reviews/

Comment: Or https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/196574 "Synthesis: [...] The putting together of parts or elements so as to make up a complex whole; the combination of immaterial or abstract things, or of elements into an ideal or abstract whole."

Answer (score -3):

In my opinion, the term "synthetic review" is a meaningless tautology because all literature reviews by definition synthesize the literature. For a definition to be meaningful, it needs to specify not only what is included but also what is not included. Obviously, a "synthetic review" synthesizes the literature. But then what is a "non-synthetic review" supposed to mean? A review that does not synthesize the literature? That is nonsense. So, the term "synthetic review" is a meaningless tautology.

So, this is not a question that can be answered in any absolute way. What one author means when they call their review "synthetic review" might be different from what another author means when they use the same term. It is not a standardized term and, in my opinion, it cannot be standardized because all reviews are "synthetic" in the sense that they all provide some sort of synthesis.

If you really want to know what a specific author means when they use that term, then you need to read what they say about it. For example, [with the specific article you mentioned](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11412-011-9131-y), other than in their title, the word "synthetic" occurs only once:

> In the light of this, and aware of the equivocal overall association between digital technologies and learning (Weaver 2000; Fuchs and Woessmann 2004), this **synthetic review** aims to identify more precisely design relationships between the technological characteristics of large multi-touch surfaces (such as those in Fig. 1) and their pedagogical possibilities, so as to increase the likelihood of improving learning, and collaborative learning in particular, as they are adopted in classroom settings.

So, in this article, I would say that "synthetic review" is a fluff term that means nothing other than that their review synthesizes the literature (which is what all reviews do, anyways).

Although you might not like this answer, I recommend that you drop the question and not bother to try to "understand" what people mean when they use a tautological term that adds no meaning.

Comment: Synthesis implies that new result/insights are obtained by combining results available in the literature. A literature review, may or may not provide such additional insights. In certain contexts novel synthesis may be undesirable, see for example Wikipedia's strict ban on synthesis: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:No_original_research#Synthesis_of_published_material

Comment: @TimRias First, the difference between "additional insights" and "combining results" is very subjective. There is no objective criterion I know of that can say that compiling all results in one place is NOT an "insight" even if nothing more is added beyond bringing things together. This would be like saying that a telephone book (old example, I know) is not a synthesis because it adds nothing--I would say it is a valuable synthesis that brings things together that are otherwise very scattered. Second, Wikipedia is not a literature review, so I'm not sure how citing its policy is relevant here.

Comment: @TimRias As a counterpoint, can you provide an example of a literature review that clearly does NOT synthesize literature in any meaningful sense? I am unable to find such an example, unless you insist that an accumulation of results cannot possibly be considered to be "synthesis". But I hope you see why that is a subjective opinion that reasonable people can disagree with.

Comment: I would say that merrily collecting results in one place -- while clearly adding value -- does not constitute any synthesis. Moreover, there are quite a few reviews that are simply a summary of who obtained what result when without attempting to derive knew insights from  combining the results in question (most literature review sections in papers are of this type). Then there are pedagogical reviews that don't really synthesize earlier results by combining, but rephrase them in way that is easier to understand.

Comment: Here is an example of a review that does not strive to do any synthesis: https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0264-9381/32/12/124006/meta

Comment: @TimRias What about writing your own answer?

Comment: @TimRias I only glanced through the article you linked, but I find it hard to understand why you would say that such an in-depth historical tracing of a major scientific development is not a "synthesis". That would suggest that it does not take much originality to select the appropriate historical cases and arrange them in a meaningful order. However, I most certainly consider such a historical review to be a "synthesis". But again, I maintain that the idea of what counts as synthesis or not is essentially subjective, so I respect if you disagree.